# How to solve Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider in angularjs while connect laravel database

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, laravel

I am new to Angularjs. I'm trying to create a simple page to connect angularjs and backend laravel database by follow some tutorials.

I keep receive **error** as:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider.

I dont know what was wrong in the code. I hope anyone help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance

**Index.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="App">
    <div class="container" >
        <div ng-controller="Controller">
            <form name="form" ng-submit="submitComment()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sa" name="author" ng-model="commentData.author">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Comment</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sa" name="comment" ng-model="commentData.comment">
                </div>
             <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    angular.module('commentService',[])
    .factory('comment',function($http){
        return{
            save:function(commentData){
              return $http({
                method:"POST",
                url:'/api/comments',
                data:commentData
              })
            }
 }
    });
    var app = angular.module('App',['commentService']);
    app.controller('Controller',function($scope,Comment){
          $scope.commentData={};
           $scope.submitComment=function(){
            Comment.save($scope.commentData);
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the below block of code.

```
var app = angular.module('App',['commentService']);
app.controller('Controller',function($scope,comment){
      $scope.commentData={};
       $scope.submitComment=function(){
        comment.save($scope.commentData);
      }
});
```

Since there is no factory with name as `Comment` in your code. The alternate solution will be to write a factory with name as `Comment`.